# Joomla Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::execute() config.php on line 27

Tags: joomla, module, frontend, edit, fatal-error

When I try to edit a module from the front-end of my joomla website I got the following error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::execute() in /home/eldvigat/public_html/2/components/com_config/config.php on line 27`

It worked before several months, but yesterday I tried it again and it does not.

Several weeks ago, In the administrator panel I was asked to update Joomla and I did so.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

Updated the joomla from version 3.3.6 to 3.4.5 and now the modules are editable.

Just the problem is that you may not see the update available, but after Purge-ing the cache the update appeared.

regards!